# Set custom variables from method

Tags: java

I have some `String` variables:

```
private String cur, last, avg, vol, shop;
```

I have method which accept `String` and gives me some result:

```
public void SomeMethod(String somestring)
{
    //Here some action with `string`
    System.out.print(result)
}
```

So i want to put `result` into one of `String` variables, but this variable must be named as value of `somestring` in my method. Some method which compare `somestring` with existent variables names. Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: Via Reflection, it's possible :)

Comment: Probably with reflection you can do it, but it's really a bad solution to me... What are you trying to accomplish? Why should you change variable names according to their contents?

Comment: I don't want change variable names. I just want compare name of variable and value of `somestring` and set value of that variable as result.

Comment: This is not probably what you want. As a var's name will never be relevant to your program's usage in runtime (unless you're making a debugging tool or a compiler or something, are you ?).

Comment: Nope. But it's what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about variable variable name. They're a native feature in PHP, but not in Java, however you can achieve similar functionality using a `HashMap`, or using Reflection. I'm going to show you the `HashMap` option, because frankly Reflection is the work of Satan.

**Example**

Now the way to implement this is like this:

```
public void someMethod(String name, String value)
{
    values.put(name, value);
}
```

And you can retrieve them with

```
public void getValue(String name)
{
    return values.get(name);
}
```

I won't write the code for you, because it's a simple transformation to get this to work in your use case.

**A hint because I'm feeling nice**

You can replace all of your `String` variables with a `Map` implementation. Then simply add the values to the `Map`, as and when the need arises.

Comment: I thought there is maybe a way to get variable names and compare, but some kind of array is working too. Thanks.

Comment: There is, `Reflection`, but by using `Reflection`, you achieve the exact same functionality in a much, much less efficient way. And this isn't an `array`. It's a `Map`.

Comment: Ok. Not array, but collection?